# How to check availability of docker desktop in a PC pragmatically with java

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, netbeans-platform

I have an IDE that I program my self, which has an action to run a **docker-compose.yml** file using 
`docker-compose up`

The action should only available when the developer has the docker desktop installed. How can I check the availability of docker desktop with java?

```
if(dockerDesktopAvailable()){
   // my action is here
}
```

Comment: WHile you can surely do that Programmatically, but there are sure inbuilt status tools in every cloud platform which you can sync on your Fav IDEs.

Comment: @VishwaRatna I want to check if the docker runs locally.

Comment: `List<Container> containers = dockerClient.listContainersCmd()
  .withShowSize(true)
  .withShowAll(true)
  .withStatusFilter("exited").exec()`

Comment: No such class as DockerClient. Can you please specify the package name ?

Comment: Yes, `<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.docker-java</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.14</version>
</dependency>`